# Perl: How to print a line to a file from within a while loop?

Tags: perl, while-loop

I have a very basic perl script which prints the next line in a text file after matching a search pattern.

```
@ARGV = <dom_boot.txt>;
while ( <> ) {
    print scalar <> if /name=sacux445/;
}
```

Which works, However I would like to capture the output into a file for further use, rather than printing it to `STDOUT`.
I'm just learning (slowly) so attempted this:

```
my $fh;
my $dom_bootdev = 'dom_bootdev.txt';

open ($fh, '>', $dom_bootdev) or die "No such file";

@ARGV = <dom_boot.txt>;
while ( <> ) {
    print $fh <> if /name=sacux445/;  
}

close $fh;
```

But I get a syntax error.

> syntax error at try.plx line 19, near "<>"

I'm struggling to figure this out. I'm guessing it's probably very simple so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Luke.

Comment: Try replace `print  $fh <>` with `print $fh scalar <>` or simply use Bash redirection on your original Perl script to save its output to a file

Comment: Please always `use strict; use warnings;` before any coding.

Comment: Thanks. I had included use strict and use warnings, but did not include them in my paste. Unfortunately i had tried these suggestions to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

The Perl parser sometimes has problems with indirect notation. The canonical way to handle it is to wrap the handle into a block:

```
print {$fh} <> if /name=sacux445/;
```

Are you sure you want to remove [scalar](http://p3rl.org/scalar)?

Comment: No, i didn't - typo on my part. But the {} didn't work either. 
Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @BillSwift: What do you mean by "didn't work"? It works for me in 5.10.1 and 5.18.2.

Answer (score 2):

Simply fetch the next line within the loop and print it, if the line matches the pattern:

```
while (<>) {
  next unless /name=sacux445/;
  my $next = <>;
  last unless defined $next;
  print $fh $next;
}
```

Note, you need to check the return value of the diamond operator.

*Input*

```
name=sacux445 (1)
aaa
name=sacux445 (2)
bbb
name=sacux445 (3)
```

*Output*

```
aaa
bbb
```

Comment: Per the first sentence in the OP's question, he meant to print the next line, not the current line.

Comment: This worked to some extent, but unfortunately printed the line i was searching for, and not the line after.

Comment: @BillSwift, I've updated the answer. I have somehow missed the part where you mentioned the next line.

Comment: Does not work. Two lines are fetched for each iteration of the loop. Put an extra line at the top of your sample and nothing will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

One should learn to use state machines for parsing data. A state machine allows the input read to be in only one place in the code. Rewriting the code as a state machine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie; # See http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html

my $dom_bootdev = 'dom_bootdev.txt';
open ( my $fh, '>', $dom_bootdev ); # autodie handles open errors

use File::Glob qw( :bsd_glob ); # Perl's default glob() does not handle spaces in file names
@ARGV = glob( 'dom_boot.txt' );

my $print_next_line = 0;
while( my $line = <> ){

    if( $line =~ /name=sacux445/ ){
        $print_next_line = 1;
        next;
    }

    if( $print_next_line ){
        print {$fh} $line;
        $print_next_line = 0;
        next;
    }

}
```

**When To Us a State Machine**

If the data is context-free, it can be parsed using only regular expressions.

If the data has a tree structure, it can be parsed using a simple state machine.

For more complex structures, a least one state machine with a push-down stack is required. The stack records the previous state so that the machine can return to it when the current state is finished.

The most complex data structure in use is XML. It requires a state machine for its syntax and a second one with a stack for its semantics.